# tracking user interaction on activity from android services

Tags: java, android

I need to track user interaction on activity from android services,i.e is there any method in android services which will be called whenever user interacts with the view in android,can anyone help me in solving this?

Answer (score 2):

Use Google Analytics Library [Getting Started](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/)

The Google Analytics SDK for Android makes it easy for native Android developers to collect user engagement data from their applications. Developers can then use the Google Analytics reports to measure:

- The number of active users are using their applications.
- From where in the world the application is being used.
- Adoption and usage of specific features.
- Crashes and exceptions.
- In-app purchases and transactions.

Comment: Hi,I need to confirm,there are no methods in native android(android services)for tracking user interaction?I need to get message whenever user touches the view or interacts with the view?

Comment: Yes You can use events, check this https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/events

Comment: Hi,but form android service class is there any methods for tracking user interaction or is there any notification/broadcast message to capture the user interaction, to get the handle of user interaction?

Answer (score 0):

you can use FLURRY Analytics API and logevents using it whenever your user uses the app for example i used flurry to check what websites user adds in my rss feed app. depending on this information i can ship my next version of app with most used websites in it already present